# Same Time Web Service Access Testing

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-4.0

I want to test my web service if a number of clients access it at the same time, not even a `0.01e-1000` millisecond difference (if it is even feasible).

**How do you create such test that would access the web service at the same time?** And if possible, how would you know that the clients access the service at the same time?

I am not sure if using a `BackgroundWorker` will execute them at the same time.

```
bgw.DoWork += DoWorkEventHandler(AccessServiceWithMockClient1);
bgw.DoWork += DoWorkEventHandler(AccessServiceWithMockClient2);
bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

I think it will execute the first one (`AccessServiceWithMockClient1`), I'm just not sure because I can't check who's accessing the service.

And of course, I think threading wouldn't work because I might have a code like this inside the other thread method.

```
AccessServiceWithMockClient1();
AccessServiceWithMockClient2();
```

Which obviously would execute the first one. But I'm not that sure, I might just not that knowledgeable about threading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're looking for a load testing tool which can simulate multiple simultaneous users.  If you have apache installed you can use apache bench http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html, which in my experience is very easy to run tests.  For Microsoft-specific tools, this question has some answers: https://serverfault.com/questions/917/what-are-good-load-testing-tools-for-iis-7-web-applications.